# Create tinymce editors dynamically

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a web application which consists in many tabs, each containing one textarea (which is used for placing a tinymce editor). In the bottom of the page, there is also a table grid, where the user can select different document "models". Each model contains a different number of tabs (each tab is a "title" or topic in the document). 
The first time I load the page, all the tabs are loaded, and the tinymce editors are rendered as well. But when I click in an item in the grid and new tabs are loaded, the tinymce editors are not rendered anymore. My init function works like this:

```js
tinymce.init({
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "txt",
    ...
 });
```

All my textareas have this class (txt) and they are all created prior the execution of the function, but by some reason the editors are not being created accordingly. Anybody had experienced similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem, which consists on creating a new tinymce editor instance for each tab and then using the "render" function to make it appear on screen. I put the following code snippet inside a "for" loop, which goes through all the tabs on the page:

```
   var ed = new tinymce.Editor(id, {
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector: "txt",
        other_setting: "0"
    }, tinymce.EditorManager);

    ed.render();
```